# Динамическое выделение памяти и умные указатели

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointer

Как можно выделить память для массива с использованием `shared_ptr`?

Я пытался делать как-то так, но оно крашится при выполнении.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template<class T> using sPtr = shared_ptr<T>;

int main() {
  unsigned int size = 10;
  sPtr<int[]> array = make_shared<int[]>(size);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    array[i] = i;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    cout << array[i] << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Такое будет поддерживается лишь с C++20. Ваш компилятор уже поддерживает C++20?

Comment: @AnT нет, я использую С++11, а как сделать выделение памяти с умным указателем в этом стандарте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, прочитав ветку эту ветку на англоязычном Stack Owerflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061979/shared-ptr-to-an-array-should-it-be-used

Если кратко, то заменить

```cpp
sPtr<int[]> array = make_shared<int[]>(size);
```

На

```cpp
sPtr<int[]> array(new int[size], std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

Потому что make_shared() выделяет память под единичный элемент, а не под массив (по крайней мере в `C++11`)